# using Python tokenizer for elasticsearch in django project

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a Django project that I want to incorporate Elasticsearch. I am using elasticsearch-py for this purpose. In my project, I need to segment Chinese too, and I found a good python library for this ([jieba for Chinese](https://github.com/fxsjy/jieba)).

jieba also has [elasticsearch-jieba-plugin](https://github.com/sing1ee/elasticsearch-jieba-plugin). I can use this plugin for sure.

But I am wondering since I am using python anyway, can I just use [jieba-py](https://github.com/fxsjy/jieba) ?

Or, do I have to use something written in Java in order to work with elasticsearch? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the official plugins that are maintained and have support on the forum, except if you have really specific needs.

Check the page here you may find the analyzer of your dreams.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis.html

> But I am wondering since I am using python anyway, can I just use jieba-py ?

Yes and no, depends on your needs if you plan to search the elasticsearch plugin is enough.

> Or, do I have to use something written in Java in order to work with elasticsearch?

No you don't need, elasticsearch-py is enough.